# Newly created azure ad group not available in azure devops (rest api)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create azure ad groups, create a devops project and grant the azure ad groups permissions.
Though I have found that the azure ad groups does not sync instantly (see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/712605/allow-manual-force-sync-azure-active-directory-to.html)

```
import json
PAT = 'MY_PAT'
cred = HTTPBasicAuth({mymail}, PAT)

#create AAD groups
projectName = 'projectdeploy6'
URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups"
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {JWT}"}
data= {
    'displayName': f'AAD_{projectName}_reader',
    'mailEnabled': 'false',
    'mailNickname': 'none',
    'securityEnabled': 'true'
    }
r = requests.post(URL, json=data,headers=headers)
string = r.content.decode('utf-8')
readerId=json.loads(string)['id']

data['displayName'] = f'AAD_{projectName}_ProjectAdmin'
r = requests.post(URL, json=data,headers=headers)
string = r.content.decode('utf-8')
adminId=json.loads(string)['id']


data['displayName'] = f'AAD_{projectName}_Contributor'
r = requests.post(URL, json=data,headers=headers)
string = r.content.decode('utf-8')
contrId=json.loads(string)['id']


# create project
requesturl = f"https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"
data = {
                "name": projectName,
                "description": "description is requred",
                "capabilities": {
                    "versioncontrol": {
                    "sourceControlType": "Git"
                    },
                    "processTemplate": {
                    "templateTypeId": "6b724908-ef14-45cf-84f8-768b5384da45"
                    }
                }
            } 
r = requests.post(requesturl, json = data, auth=cred)

time.sleep(15)

url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/projects/{projectName}?api-version=6.0"
r = requests.get(url, auth=cred)
project = json.loads(r.content)

url= f"https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/graph/descriptors/{project['id']}"
r = requests.get(url, auth=cred)
projectScp =json.loads(r.content)['value']


#get AAD groups
url = 'https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=5.1-preview.1'
r = requests.get(url, auth=cred)
d = json.loads(r.content)
adminAADGroup =[group for group in d['value'] if group['originId'] == adminId][0]
readerAADGroup =[group for group in d['value'] if group['originId'] == readerId][0]
contrAADGroup =[group for group in d['value'] if group['originId'] == contrId][0]

# get ADO groups
url = f"https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1&scopeDescriptor={projectScp}&$search='displayName:projectdeploy1 Team'"
r = requests.get(url, auth=cred)
d = json.loads(r.content)
adminADOGroup = [group for group in d['value'] if group['displayName'] == 'Project Administrators'][0]
contrADOGroup = [group for group in d['value'] if group['displayName'] == 'Contributors'][0]
readerADOGroup = [group for group in d['value'] if group['displayName'] == 'Readers'][0]


url = f"https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/graph/memberships/{adminAADGroup['descriptor']}/{adminADOGroup['descriptor']}?api-version=6.1-preview.1"
r = requests.put(url, auth=cred)
json.loads(r.content)
```

This fails at this line:

```
adminAADGroup =[group for group in d['value'] if group['originId'] == adminId][0]
```

I found that if i go into the devops web portal, and search for the adminAAD group, it will synk and rerunning the script will result in the next line failing (getting the contributor group).

I tried to use postman to intercept the calls, and found it uses theese API's.
PATCH [https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/IdentityPicker/Identities/me/mru/common](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borg%7D/_apis/IdentityPicker/Identities/me/mru/common)

I captured the call in postman, but i am trying to call it again i get an internal server error

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: GUID.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.IdentityPicker.IdentityPickerArgumentException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server",
    "typeKey": "IdentityPickerArgumentException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

Has anyone had success with any of the above?

Comment: Can  you search the contributor  group in azure devops portal, when there was error getting the contributor group. Since there is a delay for azure devops service to sync with azure ad. Could you try  calling the `get AAD groups ` api? when all the newly created groups can be searched in azure devops portal.

Comment: the groups can be accessed instantly from the devops portal, i believe the call to _apis/IdentityPicker/Identities/me/mru/common syncronizes.
edit: to clarify, If i search for the newly created group in the portal, they show up. After srarching they also show up in ´get ADO groups´ API. If i dont search for them first using the portal, the ´get ADO groups´ API does not return them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested and got the same result. It seems that the AAD group can only be retrieved by `get ADO groups API` after it is searched in ADO portal.

I saw you were trying adding the AAD groups to ADO groups via ADO rest api.  You can use [Groups - Create rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#add-an-aad-group-as-member-of-a-group) as workaround. There is no need to get the aad group's descriptor first. You can use the `Object Id` of the AAD group directly.

**POST**:

```
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups?groupDescriptors={adminADOGroup['descriptor']}&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
  "originId": adminId
}
```